# If $\mathrm A$, $\mathrm B$, and $\mathrm C$ are three points, find $\overrightarrow {AB} + \overrightarrow {BC} + \overrightarrow {CA}$

Tags: geometry, vectors

> If $\mathrm A$, $\mathrm B$, and $\mathrm C$ are three points, find $\overrightarrow {AB} + \overrightarrow {BC} + \overrightarrow {CA}$

Hints on how to get started with this one?

Comment: Draw a picture, then remember how you add vectors.

Comment: @Chappers Thanks!  I actually did draw a picture, which is a triangle but I guess I'm confused the word 'find.'  I assume a pictures suffices to answers to this question.

Comment: Or, look for **Chasles relation** on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\overrightarrow{AB}+\overrightarrow{BC}=\overrightarrow{AC}$. Can you continue?

Comment: Hi Bernard, I know this is a very late comment, but I'm having trouble following the logic.  Would you mind elaborating a little more for me?

Comment: @inquisitor: Use repeatedly *Chasles' relation*:  $\;(\overrightarrow{AB}+\overrightarrow{BC})+\overrightarrow{CA}=\overrightarrow{AC}+\overrightarrow{CA}=\overrightarrow{AA}$.